# HTML calling Java Methods

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, apex

The outcome of the scripts below is to have the HTML call the Java file, and have that Java file execute with the text that was extracted from the HTML text-boxes. I've made sure the API's (servlet, APEX) are correctly installed.

**Java**

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class webConnAPI extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User temp = new User();
        temp.setfname(request.getParameter("fname"));
        temp.setlname(request.getParameter("lname"));
        temp.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        temp.setPword(request.getParameter("pword"));

        EmailServer addUser = new EmailServer();
        addUser.Users.add(temp);
}
```

**JavaScript Function Called by the button**

```
<script>
        function addData(){
            try{
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                        var data = xhr.responseText;
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
                xhr.open('GET', 'webConnAPI', true);
                xhr.send(null);
            }catch(Excetpion){
                alert('didnt work');
            }
        }
</script>
```

**HTML**

The Text boxes and the buttons.

```
 <form name="form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webConnAPI" method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>
         <h2>
            <!--Not Useful to Question-->
         </h2>
      </legend>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <p>
         <!-- not Important to Question-->
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type = "text"
            id = "email"
            value = "Email" 
            name = "email"/>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>Password</label>
         <input type = "password"
            id = "pword"
            value = "password"
            name = "pword"/>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>First Name</label>
         <input type = "text"
            id = "fname"
            value = "First Name" 
            name = "fname"/>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>Last Name</label>
         <input type = "text"
            id = "lname"
            value = "Last Name"
            name = "lname"/>
      </p>
      <div>
         <button type="submit" id="buttonJoin" onclick="addDate()">Join</button>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button onclick="buttonLogin" type="submit" name="buttonLogin">Login</button>  
      </div>
      <div>
         <button onclick="buttonReset" type="reset" nwame="buttonReset">Reset</button>  
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <div id="data"></div>
   <div id="showDiv"  style="display:none;">Thanks</div>
</form>
```

I really don't understand the problem and I would be very grateful if I could get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webConnAPI may be the reason. Make sure you have JSTL or spring

Comment: addData not spelled correctly .. also see if its a GET call

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" id="buttonJoin" onclick="addDate()">Join</button>
```

you misspelled addData() method in onClick event of Join Button.